# Convert duration string into seconds integer

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I want to turn strings that represent durations into their duration in seconds as an integer.

All of the strings are formatted in the following way:

```
hh:mm:ss
```

I was working with substrings, which I cast to integers and then multiplied with 3600, 60 or 1 respectively and in the end summed everything up.

Just like this:

`SELECT
cast(substr(time_string, 1, 2) as smallint) * 3600 + cast(substr(time_string, 4, 2) as smallint) * 60 + cast(substr(time_string, 7, 2) as smallint) as seconds
from table_name`

As I have to do this for multiple fields, I would be interested in a better way to achieve this result. My search for a better solution, though, fell flat so far.

I would appreciate any input or help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`date_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions), cast to time and use [`date_diff`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_diff) with required unit:

```sql
select date_diff(
        'second',
        time '00:00:00', -- zero time
        cast(date_parse('12:10:56', '%T') as time)
    ) seconds
```

Output:

| seconds |
| --- |
| 43856 |

Comment: Thank you very much.
Works perfectly and is very easily understandable.